# How to debug solr query not returning records

Tags: tomcat, solr, schema

I am working to get solr working with my organization. It is setup as multicore solr 3.6 on tomcat 6.

So far I have modified the sample schema.xml to accept the specific fields for our records. Records are going in no problem and when I run a query for all records (`?q=*:*`) it returns everything. But when I query for specific terms that are absolutely in the records (e.g. `?q=green` or `?q=product_description:green`), no results come up. Though if I insert some of the default example docs like ipod_video.xml or ipod_other.xml, those records do come up if it search for them (e.g. `?q=ipod` or `?q=video`)

All of our new fields are defined with `indexed=true` on them so I am not sure why our own records are not coming up at all if we query them.

Any ideas how to debug this behavior?

**UPDATE** - adding schema.xml and solrconfig.xml details.

*schema.xml is virtually the same as the default schema.xml that comes with solr 3.6 but with these added fields*:

```
<fields>
<field name="search_title" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="search_prefix" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="search_description" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="search_content" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="product_date" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="product_thumbnail" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>

<field name="product_type" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
<field name="product_updatepricefunction" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="tagids" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="tagid" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<dynamicField name="*_tag" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="event_id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="activity_id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="activity_function_code" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="search_room" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="weekday" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="activity_weekday" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="activity_begindate" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="activity_begintime" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"  multiValued="true"/>
<field name="activity_endtime" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="audience" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="format" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"   multiValued="true"/>
<field name="publish_date" type="date" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="isbn" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true" />
<field name="product_code" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true"/>
</fields>

<uniqueKey>product_code</uniqueKey>
```

*and here is the request handler from solrconfig.xml*:

```
<requestHandler name="/select" class="solr.SearchHandler">
<!-- default values for query parameters can be specified, these
     will be overridden by parameters in the request
  -->
 <lst name="defaults">
   <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
   <int name="rows">10</int>
   <str name="df">text</str>
 </lst>
<!-- In addition to defaults, "appends" params can be specified
     to identify values which should be appended to the list of
     multi-val params from the query (or the existing "defaults").
  -->
<!-- In this example, the param "fq=instock:true" would be appended to
     any query time fq params the user may specify, as a mechanism for
     partitioning the index, independent of any user selected filtering
     that may also be desired (perhaps as a result of faceted searching).

     NOTE: there is *absolutely* nothing a client can do to prevent these
     "appends" values from being used, so don't use this mechanism
     unless you are sure you always want it.
  -->
<!--
   <lst name="appends">
     <str name="fq">inStock:true</str>
   </lst>
  -->
<!-- "invariants" are a way of letting the Solr maintainer lock down
     the options available to Solr clients.  Any params values
     specified here are used regardless of what values may be specified
     in either the query, the "defaults", or the "appends" params.

     In this example, the facet.field and facet.query params would
     be fixed, limiting the facets clients can use.  Faceting is
     not turned on by default - but if the client does specify
     facet=true in the request, these are the only facets they
     will be able to see counts for; regardless of what other
     facet.field or facet.query params they may specify.

     NOTE: there is *absolutely* nothing a client can do to prevent these
     "invariants" values from being used, so don't use this mechanism
     unless you are sure you always want it.
  -->
<!--
   <lst name="invariants">
     <str name="facet.field">cat</str>
     <str name="facet.field">manu_exact</str>
     <str name="facet.query">price:[* TO 500]</str>
     <str name="facet.query">price:[500 TO *]</str>
   </lst>
  -->
<!-- If the default list of SearchComponents is not desired, that
     list can either be overridden completely, or components can be
     prepended or appended to the default list.  (see below)
  -->
<!--
   <arr name="components">
     <str>nameOfCustomComponent1</str>
     <str>nameOfCustomComponent2</str>
   </arr>
  -->
</requestHandler>
```

Comment: Can you help me with your schema.xml file?

Comment: sorry i don't understand what you mean, could you be more specific?

Comment: I want to see your schema.xml file and the /select requestHandler from  solr-config.xml file.

Comment: ok thanks, I added those details (though only the new stuff that I added to the example schema.xml that comes with solr 3.6 since it's a rather long file).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `q=<search phrase>` means, search from the default field that is mentioned. However, if you have not specified a default field or you want to query a specific field other than the default field you should query Solr like `q=<fieldname>:<search phrase>`.

Solr provides a variety of analyzers that you can use to index documents according to your requirement. Have a look [here](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/).

**EDIT after question update**

1st - The `/select` `requestHandler` has the field `text` as default and you schema.xml file does not have a field named text.

2nd - In your schema.xml file the fields `search_title`, `search_description`, `search_content`, `audience` and `format` are of type `text_general` which is tokenized. All the other fields are of type `String`.

3rd - To search in a field of type `String`, you need to have the exact search phrase or you need to use wildcards. For e.g. if your document has the value `green` in the `product_type`   field then the query `q=product_type:green` would give you the document in the search result. However if you have the value `green color` in the `product_type` field the the query `q=product_type:green` will not give any output. But the query `q=product_type:green*` would give you a document in the search result.

I think i have given you a head start and the basic information about Solr. You should now go ahead and read from the link I provided above.

Comment: sorry, I should have added that this also is not working for any of our own records (using `q=<fieldname>:<search phrase>`). I updated the original question to clarify this.

Comment: I want to see your schema.xml file and the /select requestHandler from solr-config.xml file.

Comment: sorry, my bad, it appears that <fieldname>:<search phrase> does work for *some* fields, but not all.

Comment: Added a detailed explanation.

Comment: the link has been redirected. [this](https://doc.lucidworks.com/lucidworks-hdpsearch/2.5/Guide-Solr.html) and [this](https://doc.lucidworks.com/fusion-server/4.1/solr-reference-guide/7.2.1/solr-tutorial.htmll) page are now provided by Lucidworks.